# FFmpeg VP9 - Different Quantisation Parameters but same output files

Tags: encoding, ffmpeg, vp9

I want to encode a video with vp9 with different quantisation parameters (qp=[16,20,24,28,32]). Unfortunately the output files have the same data rate after encoding and don't show any quality differences.

This is my code for qp=20:

```
ffmpeg -s:v 3840x1920 -framerate 30 -i video_3840x1920_30fps_8bit_420_erp.yuv -c:v libvpx-vp9 -qp 20 -f avi out.avi
```

Many thanks for any pointers you can give me.

Comment: I don't see any generic or private `qp` option applicable to vpx. You can try with `-qmin N -qmax N`.

Comment: NO!!!!!! Do not ever use -qmin/-qmax with libvpx unless you very specifically know what you are doing. Using -qmin/-qmax wrongly is almost universally the reason that until today, some people find that vp9 (or even av1) is significantly worse than x264.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-qp` only works for internal `mpegvideoenc`-derived encoders, such as FFmpeg's built-in MPEG-1/2/4 encoders. Libvpx, like x264/5, uses `-crf` to do this instead. See the [Wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/VP9#constantq) for more details. You can also type `ffmpeg -h encoder=libvpx-vp9`:

```
$ ffmpeg -h encoder=libvpx-vp9
[..]
  -crf               <int>        E..V.... Select the quality for constant quality mode (from -1 to 63) (default -1)
```

So for qp=20, you would use `ffmpeg -s:v 3840x1920 -framerate 30 -i video_3840x1920_30fps_8bit_420_erp.yuv -c:v libvpx-vp9 -crf 20 -b:v 0 out.avi`.